# Trying to use reactive-native-osc to send informations to a unity game throught a smartphone

Tags: react-native, osc

first of all I'm new to react native things, I apologize for any stupid mistakes I could do.

I'm trying to control a Unity games throught a smartphone that's why I'm trying to make a react native application and to use the react-native-osc module that i found on Github (here the Github link : https://github.com/luiscript/react-native-osc.git).

I'm struggling with the integration, like when I tried to import it on my blank new react native project, i got errors about version : [Import error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtkGX.png)

So I tried to add the --force in my command line to see if it could still work.
Look like I was wrong because now I can't use the osc.createClient() or the osc.sendMessage() function from the module, I'm getting error like this : [react native error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6xIf.png)

I'm not sure it come from the installation of the module but I guess it didn't help, so if anyone have any idea, I will be grateful.

I tried to add things like updating the module or the version or looking on internet but can't find anything that worked for me.

I'm trying to contact the guy who made the module so if he sees this message, please let me know.

Comment: Please post error messages as text, image. You can [edit] your question.

Comment: Well, I created my account recently so I can't embed image yet, need more "reputation" ^^' Sorry about that.